# Google Play Game Service Ranking

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am working on Google play game service
    I have integrated code for real time player and its working.
    Now i want to know some more feature that 
    I did not found after searching on Google are below

```
 1. When user won the game it should update wining counter by one.      
 2. What is the ranking of user according to country
 3. How to get user detail of opponent.
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check out Leaderboards https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

You can create (currently) up to 70 leaderboards (maybe one for the country/regions of your players).

At the end of your game, you can update the user's score.  The server keeps track of daily, weekly, and all time leaders.  There is also the concept of Public and Social leaderboards so that may be a way to see the opponent's standing.